# Passing credentials with Ajax load to Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC site that uses authentication and authorization successfully. I am trying to query an api portion of the site using jquery and the load method. I have attempted to then use

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

and this fails, as the request is not authenticated. The page with the ajax request is sucessfully logged in. Is it possible to access its authentication token and pass this with the load request, or do I need to generate a new token in javascript?

EDIT: After some more research, I have found that this line in the WebApiConfig file:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

Is what is disabling the cookie validation for ajax requests. It makes it so only the token method is evaluated. By default MVC uses cookies, and web api uses tokens. I was trying to utilise two different authentication schemes. As the cookie is sent automatically with the ajax requests, the User.Identity is then filled. This answers my original question.

However, this is considered insecure and allows for CRSF attacks. Therefore, token is desirable.

So, reworded, **can you use an existing authentication cookie with the /token endpoint to generate an authentication token?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a workable solution with the minimum amount of effort.

The ApplicationOAuthProvider is the default provider. It provides an endpoint at /token that you can call with your username and password. In return it provides an authorization cookie, and more importantly a bearer token in the body of the response.

The login flow for the user is unchanged. They visit a log in form, and enter their credentials. This then calls the /token endpoint transparently, returning the response token and cookie. This token can then be saved using javascript to the local or session storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("token", "value");
```

This can then be retrieved for any pages loaded in the same browser session. You load this value and pass it in the headers of the ajax request, which then authenticates with the web api.

Use session storage if the user specifies they should not be remembered, otherwise local storage will mean the token is available more often. You do have to check both stores however, and there is a risk the token is invalid from expiration. If this occurs as signalled by an authorization error in the ajax request, you can easily display a message and redirect the user to the sign in page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following steps to achieve your goal:

1. Read authentication cookie on the client  using jquery cookies plugin or whatever.
2. Create an Web API endpoint to handle AJAX authentication which accepts cookie as a body parameter.
3. Parse authentication cookie, get user information from it and return a token.
4. Use generated token for subsequent reqeuests.